# Modular multiplicative inverse proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

Does the concept of modular multiplicative inverse require a proof or is it taken as a definition?

Suppose $5/4 \equiv 3$ (mod $7$).

Can that even be written in the standard $a = bq + r$ notation and proven from there?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  To demonstrate that $5\times 4^{-1}\equiv 3 \pmod 7$ you just need to show that $5\equiv 3\times 4 \pmod 7$ which is clear.

Answer (score 1):

What the statement means is that $5 \times 4^{-1} \equiv 3 \pmod{7}$.

The modular inverse of $4$ is defined as the number $x$ such that $4x\equiv 1 \pmod{7}$ (if it exists), and it's easy to check that $x=2$ satisfies this.

So $5 \times 4^{-1} \equiv 5 \times 2 \equiv  3 \pmod{7}$.

Alternatively, $5/4$ can be defined as the number that when multiplied by $4$, gives $5$, and $3 \times 4\equiv 12 \equiv 5 \pmod{7}$ as required.

Answer (score 0):

$5/4 \equiv 3\pmod 7$ means

$5 \times 4^{-1} \equiv 3 \pmod 7$ or $5 \times 2  \equiv 3 \pmod 7,$

so $5 \equiv 12 \pmod 7$ (i.e., $5=-1\times7+12) $ or $10 \equiv 3 \pmod 7$ (i.e., $10=1\times7+3),$

but $4^{-1} \pmod 7$ is different from $1/4$ as a real number.

Comment: Re: claim in last sentence: do you claim the same for $1/4$ the rational number, and do you also claim that $\,4\pmod 7\,$ differs from $4$ the integer?  What precisely do you mean by "different from"?

Comment: @BillDubuque:  yes, also different from 1/4 as rational number.  $4 \pmod 7$ is an equivalence class, which contains the integer $4$ as well as $11, -3$, etc.   By "different from" I meant you don't say something like $1/4=0.25 \equiv 2 \pmod 7$ or $5/4=1.25=7q+3$ with $q \in \mathbb Z$

Comment: fyi: in algebra we do often overload / abuse  notation in this way, e.g. we use $4$ to denote the equivalence class $[4]_7 = 4+7\Bbb Z\,$, and we use $1/4$ to denote $[4]_7^{-1} = 2+7\Bbb Z,\,$ which makes sense because the natural map $\,\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z_7\,$ extends *uniquely* to the subring of rationals writable with denominator coprime to $7$ (universal property of localization), via $\, a/b\mapsto [a]_7[b]_7^{-1}.\,$ This implies that (ring) arithmetic of such fractions maps homomorphically into $\,\Bbb Z_7,\,$ e.g. $\,1/2- 1/3 = 1/6\,$ maps to $\, 4 - 5 \equiv 6.\ \ $

Comment: Wouldn't you say $1/4$ means something different in the context of $\mathbb Z_7$ vs. $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb R$, and could you write $5/4=7q+3$ as OP asked?

Comment: The point is that in certain contexts such overloaded *notation* is fruitful because it helps us to smoothly  import intuition from closely related structures. The context usually determines precisely how "different" we wish to view such related objects. In all the rings that you mention $\,1/4\,$ denotes  the inverse of $4$, i.e. the unique solution of $\, 4x = 1,\,$ so precisely how does it "differ" in those rings?

Comment: Maybe I stated my question incorrectly. Did the person that defined multiplicative inverse simply say that it will be what it is or did it develop from some previous definitions in modular arithmetic?

Comment: The mutiplicative inverse of $4$ is the element you multiply it by to get $1$

Comment: @MichaelMunta See Wikipedia's article on [multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_inverse) for an introduction, It's the multiplicative analog of the additive operation of negation (= additive inverse). 
 The notion of inverse makes sense for any (associative) binary operation with identity element, e.g. see [monoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid).  $\Bbb Z/n = $ integers $\bmod n$ form a monoid under multiplication, so the notion of modular multiplicative inverse is a special case of the notion of inverse in monoids. See any abstract algebra textbook.

Comment: @MichaelMunta:  If $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime then there are integers $c$ and $d$ such that $ac-bd=1$ ([Bezout’s identity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BezoutsIdentity.html)) and $c$ is the multiplicative inverse of $a \pmod b$

Comment: Ok, I suppose then that it is simply defined as is.